# xmodmap remappings not working correctly in all applications

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, remapping, capslock

I remapped some of my keys using a `Mode_switch` with the following `.Xmodmap`

```
! remove Caps Lock
clear lock
clear mod1
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
remove Shift = Caps_Lock
keycode 66 = Alt_L Meta_L Escape
add mod1 = Alt_L Meta_L

! add Mode_switch
keycode 64 = NoSymbol NoSymbol
keycode 64 = Mode_switch

keycode 43 = h H Left Left
keycode 44 = j J Down Down
keycode 45 = k K Up Up
keycode 46 = l L Right Right
keycode 31 = i I Prior Prior
keycode 30 = u U Home Home
keycode 59 = comma less Next Next
keycode 48 = apostrophe quotedbl End End
keycode 22 = BackSpace BackSpace Delete Delete
```

This code first disables `Caps_Lock`, then maps `Alt_L` to `Caps_Lock` (so that `Alt_L` is now free) and then uses `Alt_L` as `Mode_switch`.

Unfortunately, this does not always work in combination with `Ctrl`. What I mean is that I would like e.g. that `Mode_switch + Ctrl + l` is interpreted as `Ctrl + right` and therefore jumps over whole words. In most programs this works fine, however in some (e.g. Mathematica) it instead just uses the shortcut for `Ctrl + l`, ignoring the `Mode_switch`.

Any ideas what is going wrong?

I am on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and do not have sudo permissions.

Comment: Confirm your ubuntu version in the output of `lsb_release -a`. Using Wayland? Check from the output of `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`.

Comment: ```No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal```
The output of ```$XDG_SESSION_TYPE``` is ```tty```

Comment: Is this a server? `xmodmap` is for X11 and will not work in TTY.

Comment: I am accessing Ubuntu from Windows via FastX2. As I said, it seems to working just fine, except for the combination with ```Ctrl``` in some programs. So it seems to me that this should be fixable through some changes in the above script.
Otherwise, could you recommend another/better way of achieving the above remapping?

Comment: I tried this from X11 and it makes no difference, i.e. the problem persists! So the xdg-session-type is not the problem